# FieldDoesNotExist with ManytoMany field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I have an issue  while running migrations, I get this error :

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Profile has no field named 'following
```

yet I have defined the field in my model, what could be the issue ?

below is my model :

```
class Profile(TimeStampedModel, models.Model):
    
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last Name'), max_length=150,
                                 null=True, blank=True)
 
    gender = models.CharField(_('Gender'), null=True, max_length=30,
                              choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='following',
                                       default=None, blank=True)
```

What could be the issue ?

**EDIT**

*Below is the stack trace :*

https://gist.github.com/huxaiphaer/abd376f43d50625bd3b10fa4829d6b0e

Migration file :

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('profiles', '0013_auto_20211108_1641'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='profile',
            name='following',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, default=None,
                                         related_name='following',
                                         to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        )
    ]
```

file : `0013_auto_20211108_1641`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('profiles', '0012_auto_20211108_0608'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='profile',
            name='following',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, default=None, null=True, related_name='following', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Share the full traceback together with the relevant view, template, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I have added the link of the stack trace, I don't think there's any connection to the views or template.

It's a migrations issue

Comment: then share the migration, [edit] the question with the *content* of the migration.

Comment: I have shared it as well @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: that is *not* the migration file: the error happens at 0013, this is 0014. This one will never be evaluated.

Comment: How did you know that it's file `0013` , I have attached it as well

Comment: So, I think, I have seen, am altering before adding right ?

Comment: because the console *prints* that it is applying 0013. It looks like you already had a m2m field before, but somehow altered it, and then created a new one. Did you by any chance removed migrations?

Comment: I suggest that you remove the `AlterField` from the operations (such that is is an empty list), normally this then should be sufficient to properly migrate.

Comment: Check your `django_migrations` table if the migration exists

Comment: I removed the `AlterField`, I removed some migrations

Comment: @ LutaayaHuzaifahIdris: please *don't* remove migrations, it only makes it worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably made a migration 0013 when you already had a `following` field, and thus that resulted in an `AlterField` migration, for a many-to-many relation that was not (yet) constructed by the migration.

You can fix the 0013 migration file by removing the `AlterField` operation, and thus making it a a "no-op migration":

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('profiles', '0012_auto_20211108_0608'),
    ]

    operations = []
```

This then will result in the migrations running again.

I would however advise *not* to remove migrations in the future. Usually it only results in problems to get the migrations back on track.